# Swift - Table View Cell displaying incorrect integer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, view

I have a table view thats acting like a little checkout basket. It works beautifully. Behind the scenes, the items are being put into an array through a service and when the user updates the quantity, it correctly registers, like so:

```
[0] App.Item    
id  UUID    
title   String  "C" 
quantity    Int 3

[1] App.Item    
id  UUID    
title   String  "B" 
quantity    Int 2

[2] App.Item    
id  UUID    
title   String  "A" 
quantity    Int 1
```

And the app is showing this all perfectly. The problem comes when I add an item with the same name. Say I add another item called C. I should also say that at this point, instead of appending to an array, I'm inserting the new values at 0, as the table view is flipped for the purpose of the design, so everythings a bit inverted, but its all good.

After adding a new C, (every item starts with a default value of 1), the console shows this:

```
[0] App.Item    
id  UUID    
title   String  "C" 
quantity    Int 1

[1] App.Item    
id  UUID    
title   String  "C" 
quantity    Int 3
```

As expected. The new value is put into the first value of the array, and the other C moves up. However on the app, the view now shows that 'A' has a value of 2, and B, C and C have values of 1. After testing it several times, the behaviour is really random. The numbers will just change to whatever it wants to be. so WHY is it perfect on the back end, but bugging out on the front.

The codebase for this project is quite extensive so I'm going to try my best to show you what's going on, but if you feel like you need more code please do just ask. Thank you so much if you even read this post! Any help would really mean a lot. Thank you :)

For adding an item, I take a value from a text field, create a new Item with the default value of 1. Add that to the array of Items using my service. Pass that array to my view controller, and my table view creates a new ItemTableViewCell using that array, like so:

```
func landingViewControllerDidPressTextFieldButton(_ viewController: LandingViewController, text: String) {
    let item = Item(title: text)
    itemService.addItem(item)
    viewController.items = itemService.getItems() //View controllers array of [Item] gets populated with the new Item array
    viewController.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .right)
  }
```

The Item service is very simple, looks like this, most importantly the 'Quantity' always starts as 1.

```
struct Item {
  let id: UUID
  let title: String
  var quantity: Int

  init(title: String, quantity: Int = 1) {
    self.id = UUID()
    self.title = title
    self.quantity = quantity
  }
}

class DefaultItemService: ItemService {

  private var items: [Item] = []

  func addItem(_ item: Item) {
    items.insert(item, at: 0)
  }

  func updateQuantity(position: Int, quantity: Int) {
    items[position].quantity = quantity
  }

  func getItems() -> [Item] {
    return items
  }
}
```

The table view code: (It switches through an enum, dynamically displaying the amount of cells equal to items.length in the view controller.)

```
case .items:
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Item", for: indexPath) as?
            ItemTableViewCell, indexPath.row < items.count else {
      return TableViewCell()
    }
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
    cell.title = items[indexPath.row].title
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
```

And what I suspect is most likely the problem, though it's proving really hard to troubleshoot. The view responsible for displaying the items. (I've edited it down to just the relevant parts)

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellDelegate: class {
  func itemTableViewCellDidChangeQuantity(_ itemCell: ItemTableViewCell, quantity: Int)
}
---
private lazy var quantityLabel = Label.main.h1Skinny(text: "1") //this used to be "\(quantity)"

private var quantity = 1

@objc func userDidTapAdd() {
    quantity += 1
    quantityLabel.text = quantity.description //again used to be \(quantity), just hoped in vain this would fix it lol
    delegate?.itemTableViewCellDidChangeQuantity(self, quantity: quantity)
  }

@objc private func userDidTapMinus() {
  guard quantity > 0 else {
    // Functionality to remove item
    return
  }
  quantity -= 1
  quantityLabel.text = quantity.description
  delegate?.itemTableViewCellDidChangeQuantity(self, quantity: quantity)
  }
```

That delegate is extended in my landing view, which simply gets the index path of the cell that has the quantity changed, and passes it into another delegate method.

```
extension LandingViewController: ItemTableViewCellDelegate {
  func itemTableViewCellDidChangeQuantity(_ itemCell: itemTableViewCell, quantity: Int) {
    guard let indexPath = homeTableView.indexPath(for: itemCell) else { return }
    delegate?.landingViewControllerItemQuantityDidChange(self, cellForRowAt: indexPath.row, quantity: quantity)
    homeTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

And finally, the functionality to change the quantity when the user presses a + or - button:

```
func landingViewControllerItemQuantityDidChange(_ viewController: LandingViewController,
                                                cellForRowAt row: Int,
                                                quantity: Int) {
  itemService.updateQuantity(position: row, quantity: quantity)
  viewController.items = itemService.getItems()
```

Comment: You should not track the quantity in the cell; cells are reused. You should update the quantity label using your item's `count` in `cellForRow` and also in your delegate functions. Even if you do want to do it the way you are doing, you need to assign to the cell's `quantity` property in `cellForRow`. Also all of that `guard...` stuff in `cellForRow` isn't necessary. Just force downcast to the right cell type and crash during development and fix any problem. It can't fail at runtime. Same thing for the array bounds check; if `numberOfRows` returns the right value you can't crash.

Comment: Hey @Paulw11, thank you so very much. I tweaked the cell so it doesn't input a value at all, so in the LandingView I did cell.quantity = items[indexPath.row].quantity and it works like a charm! 

Merry Christmas if you celebrate it, and thank you very much :D